# Style of bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I want to generate bibliography in which the style is

1. For an author’s name, full spelling of family name appears before abbreviation of given name, with **a spacing in the middle**.
2. If there are more than 3 authors, the first 3 names are followed by et al.
3. The article title should be identified by an initial capital letter with the remainder of the title in lower case.
4. For correct abbreviations of journal titles, refer to ISO, e.g., Chin Sci Bull for Chinese Science Bulletin, Sci China Math for SCIENCE CHINA Mathematics.

**Example**

```
[1]Betsakos D, Pouliasis S. Isometries for the modulus metric are quasiconformal mappings. Trans Amer Math Soc, 2019, 372: 2735–2752.
[2]Wang Q H, Lindon O, Hardle W. Semiparametric regression analysis with missing response at random. J Amer Statist Assoc, 2004, 19: 334--345
```

I tried `\bibliographystyle{acm}` and many other styles for bibtex, but all failed.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Other than the way the `acm` bibliography style formats the authors' names, are you overall ok with the way the `acm` style formats bibliographic entries?

Comment: @Mico `acm` style formats it like:  `Betsakos, D., and Pouliasis, S. Isometries for the modulus metric are quasiconformal mappings. Transactions of the American Mathematical Society 372, 4 (2019), 2735-2752.` Seems totally different

Comment: My question was [emphasis added], *Other than the way the acm bibliography style formats the authors' names*, are you overall ok with the way the acm style formats bibliographic entries?

Comment: @Mico No, they are not the one I want, thanks

Comment: So, what *do* you want - in addition to your specs for how the authors' names should be formatted? (Sorry, but my mind-reading skills are worthless.)

Comment: @Mico Thank you, I reedited my question and the format details I want.

Comment: You can make custom bibliography styles with `latex makebst`.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find an automatic method, so I finally edit it in latex manually as follows:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99} 
\bahao\baselineskip 11.5pt

\bibitem{Betsakos2019} Betsakos D, Pouliasis S. Isometries for the modulus metric are 
quasiconformal mappings. Trans Amer Math Soc, 2019, 372: 2735–2752.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Still appreciate it if there is any other good way.